# Subversion behaving weirdly behind reverse proxy

Tags: iis, svn, visualsvn-server

I'm trying to migrate a Subversion server to a different machine, which is also already running IIS. Thus, I configured Subversion to run at port `81`, and set up an IIS rewrite rule based on the host name:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="svn.foo.example" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^svn.foo.example$" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="https://svn.foo.example:81/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

In addition, "server proxy settings" are configured as follows (I think I left all of these as defaults):

- enable
- version pass through
- keep alive
- 120-second timeout
- reverse rewrite host in response headers
- preserve IP in X-Forwarded-For

(The SVN server is VisualSVN 4.3.4; the IIS is Windows Server 2019 Version 1809.)

Where things get strange is that some stuff works, including on existing working copies. For example, I can:

1. use an existing working copy
2. add a file to that folder, and commit it
3. check that file's log

However:

1. use an existing working copy
2. check the log of a *folder* // works!
3. check the log of an existing *file* // does not work!

The latter fails with `E160013: File not found`. Indeed, if I look in the IIS logs, it returns 404.

If I instead (locally) check out that same file *without* the reverse proxy, I can get its log, so presumably, it's a problem with the proxying. But then why does it work if I add *new* files and check *their* logs?

Comment: Why do you add IIS as a reverse proxy for VisualSVN Server?

Comment: Because there’s other websites running on the same machine, so ports 80/443 are already taken — but I want a smooth transition where the same ports can be used again.

Comment: Have you considered adding an additional IP interface to this server computer? This should help you with the transition and you won't need to use IIS as a reverse proxy.

Comment: You can enable failed request tracing to check the process of proxy in log file. You can refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/using-failed-request-tracing-rules-to-troubleshoot-application-request-routing-arr).